# Ubuntu running on a Acer Chromebook does not detect standard audio output, but does have HDMI out

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers, audio-jack

I'm running on an Acer Chromebook 11.
I flashed it with SeaBios and set up Ubuntu (as xubuntu w/ lxde) as the ONLY operating system. 
That is to say, I am NOT using chrubuntu. Ubuntu has a direct link to the hardware.

When I play any sound, I cannot hear it over plugged-in headphones or earbuds, or the speakers. If I go to the sound options, I can put sound over two HDMI ports, but neither option works, or detects a "plugged-in" state, although the HDMI can be plugged in and the computer only has one HDMI port.

The Chromebook I'm using has built-in speakers, but neither the speakers nor the headphone jack are ever detected by the operating system.

Here is my result from alsa-info.sh:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=be8dda16271f679cd313d0c3f3ba0f2dafe5b6e2

Help would be urgently appreciated as this computer is a birthday gift for a friend!

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.clifford.at/blog/index.php?/archives/131-Installing-Ubuntu-on-an-Acer-Chromebook-13-Tegra-K1.html) (at the end of the page) , headphones works using alsamixer (look [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer) ):
 press F6 to select 2nd device , move to "headphones" fader, press "m" to unmute.

Comment: Alsamixer doesn't show ANY faders. There are two chips, S/PDIF and S/PDIF1, but they're both locked in 00 boxes. The only card I can see is the HDA Intel PCH, and the only chip alsamixer detects is the HDMI output chip.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu like in the linked site ? instructions are here :  https://github.com/raphael/linux-samus

Comment: No. As explained, I installed ubuntu via a standard bootable USB, and I am not dual-booting chrome OS.

Comment: So , you have chances to make it work using the method shown in  the above link: this will install a special kernel.